# I want to add 1 to all elements in array by using for loop in swift. while i am trying adding number is applies to only one element

Tags: arrays, swift

```
var objArray = [1,3,4,5,2,3,4,2,3,8,6,7,10,11,23,33]

print(addArrayNumbers())


func addArrayNumbers()-> Int {
            
            var add = 0
            for objNum in objArray[0...15] {
                add  = objNum + 1
            }
            return add
        }
}
```

Comment: you can easily find the answer to your question (and many more) here:  https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/TheBasics.html

Answer (score 0):

Your code doesn't make much sense. You're not changing the contents of your array at all. You are looping through and adding the value of each element (plus one) to a total.

If you want to create a new array that adds one to every element in an existing array, your code might look like this:

```
let objArray = [1,3,4,5,2,3,4,2,3,8,6,7,10,11,23,33]

func addValue(_ value: Int, toArray array: [Int])-> [Int] {
    return array.map { $0 + value }
}
print(addValue(1, toArray: objArray))
```

If you want to change the array in place, you could use code like this:

```
 var objArray = [1,3,4,5,2,3,4,2,3,8,6,7,10,11,23,33]

 func addValue(_ value: Int, toArray array: inout [Int]) {
     array.enumerated().forEach { (index, element) in
         array[index] += value
     }
 }

print(objArray)
addValue(1, toArray: &objArray)
print(objArray)
```

### Edit:

If you specifically want to use a for in method, you could rewrite the forEach above as follows:

```
for (index, element) in array.enumerated() {
     array[index] += value
}
```

Comment: i want to do same thing using for loop method. thanks

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Comment: Note that forEach is a "for loop method". It's just a different form of for loop.